# React IIS deploy - Method not allowed

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, iis, server

I am having a problem configuring an application written in React+ Flask.
The application is uploaded to an IIS server, I have of course added a web.config file to the build folder. Seemingly everything looks fine, but the React application cannot communicate with Flask, the request is not executed - I get the message, Post method not allowed, error 405.
I added a header to web.config,
Access-Control-Allow-Methods, but that doesn't help either, I still get a 405 error.
I am very much asking for help.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've searched google and bing, I've also searched here, but nowhere can I find help that fits my problem.

Comment: To get started, you have to edit the question to show clearly how you deployed your React+Flask web apps there. There are a million ways to get something wrong, while only a few can succeed.

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue? Looking forward to your reply, thank you！

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify your Flask configuration to ensure that your Flask application is properly configured to accept POST requests. You should have a route in your Flask application that uses the `@app.route` decorator to specify the specific route you wish to receive POST requests. For example:

```
@app.route('/your_post_route', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_post_request():
     # Your code to handle the POST request here
     return render_template('your page')
```